# data is not receiving at Azure IoTHub?

Tags: json, azure, ubuntu-14.04, azure-iot-hub

I am using Azure Edge V1 with Ubuntu, I have created 1 IoT Hub with the name say X and then created 2 Devices say dev1 & dev2. After that I changed simulated_device_cloud_upload_lin.json file.
modules:
IotHub - "args": {
"IoTHubName": "X",
"IoTHubSuffix": "azure-devices.net",
"Transport": "MQTT",
"RetryPolicy": "EXPONENTIAL_BACKOFF_WITH_JITTER"}

```
   mapping - "args": [
{
  "macAddress": "01:01:01:01:01:01",
  "deviceId": "dev1",
  "deviceKey": "primary key of dev1"
},
{
  "macAddress": "02:02:02:02:02:02",
  "deviceId": "dev2",
  "deviceKey": "Primary key of dev2"
} ] }
```

And then I go inside build folder and run command
./samples/simulated_device_cloud_upload/simulated_device_cloud_upload_sample ../samples/simulated_device_cloud_upload/src/simulated_device_cloud_upload_lin.json

And this start sending messages to IoT Hub, but when I checked to IoTHub with iothub-explorer it will show me error given below-
error receiving reply from Event hub management end point : undefined.
And also messages did not reach at IoT Hub.

Could you please tell me what have I done wrong?

Comment: The way you set up the sample looks ok to me. What version of iothub-explorer did you use? Also, can you update the post with the exact iothub-explorer command you used (be sure to remove any personal information)?

Comment: Iothub-explorer version is 1.1.19   
command - ***iothub-explorer monitor-events dev1 --login "Connection String"***

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/Azure/iot-edge/issues/447) opened on GitHub.

Comment: Not sure what to tell you...I'm using iothub-explorer 1.1.19 (tried it from Windows and Ubuntu), and `monitor-events` is working for me. I used the same command you did. What happens if you create a new device and try to monitor events on it? Or what if you try to monitor events for a device in another IoT Hub? Since iothub-explorer and Device Explorer both seem to be returning an error for this, I wonder if that device and/or hub is in an odd state.